# Does a countered Mimeoplasm still exile creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I use [Counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCounterspell%5d) on a [The Mimeoplasm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThe%20Mimeoplasm%5d) that's being cast, are the 2 creatures that have to be removed still removed? Or is this a ETB effect? I ask because of the fuzzy wording on The Mimeoplasm that says as he comes into play first...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wording clearly says

> As The Mimeoplasm **enters the battlefield**, you may exile two creature cards from graveyards. If you do, it enters the battlefield as a copy of one of those cards with a number of additional +1/+1 counters on it equal to the power of the other card.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

So if it's countered, it will not enter the battlefield, the replacement effect won't happen and the creature cards won't be exiled from their graveyards.

Comment: I think the OP's confusion might be based on the difference between "*When* CN enters the battlefield," and  "*As* CN enters the battlefield," might be worth adding a small explanation in that